# Concern with jenkins multiple poms execution

Tags: jenkins

I want to create only one job of jenkins and trigger the multiple poms with it i have done the same in ant by using the conditional buildstep plugin

My actual design is that i want to use is suppose I create the one job with name ABC and i m maintaining the tar file with this name and in this job i want to maintain the multiple builds 
like ABC-type-I, ABC-type-II, ABC-type-III ........ all of them have there pom layering(maven structure) and i want to create the conditional steps like at run time i would be able to decide for which types the build is included in the tar i know that it can be done using conditional steps plugin but want to know the better approach if any in ur mind please share...........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the solution of my problem what I did is that I have used ***conditional build step  plugin*** in Jenkins, so I made the one parent pom and then make the respective child pom for each sub module of my parent module and through conditional plugin I was able to give or create the prebuildsteps(go to conditional single step or multiple and then u can give the pom.xml there of your sub module) or you can make your job as dynamic as well that if you  want to to include only sub module 1  not sub module 2 in your parent module  than you can make the checkbox there by using the boolean parameters and executes the conditional steps only when there value is true(means checked)